# Is it OK to mount outdoor electrical outlet box to deck trim board?

Tags: electrical, wiring, deck, outdoor

I see most places have outdoor outlet either standing by itself (via post or something hard) or mounted to wall. If I run my wiring under the deck and when it comes out, can I mount it on the side of my deck (trim board)? Or is there regulation requiring the outlet to be NOT touching the deck?

p.s. I am using outdoor rating stuffs like box and cover. PVC is used too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you can secure the box rigidly to the trim board in accordance with the box's listing and the trim board itself isn't flopping in the breeze, you have it made according to 314.23(A):

> **(A) Surface Mounting.** An enclosure mounted on a building or other surface shall be rigidly and securely fastened in place. If the surface does not provide rigid and secure support, additional support in accordance with other provisions of this section shall be provided.

Comment: The term "rigid" is very vague. But I know what it means. All deck trim boards are very rigid by default anyways as it's usually two (2) 2x8 lumber.